# XAML resources aren't loaded when calling from different project

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources

I have a WPF project with some styles in XAML in `Application.Resources`. This works perfectly fine. But when I open a window from this project from another one (this one is a console application), the resources from XAML aren't loaded. When I first tried it, I got a `XamlParseException` on `StaticResource` calls in XAML, so I changed it to `DynamicResource` and now the style just doesn't get loaded. How do I fix this?

The code I use:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    App app = new App();
    MyWindow wnd = new MyWindow ();
    wnd.Show();
    app.Run();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the `Run` method that takes a `Window` parameter. In your current code, you're creating and showing the window before running the app, which means the application resources aren't loaded yet.

Try:

```
App app = new App();
MyWindow wnd = new MyWindow();
app.Run(wnd);
```